# Formatting float in python also before the decimal separator

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting, tabular

I am formatting floats as follows:

```
logFile.write("Loadcase: %6i %2i %4i %2.2f %2.2f %4f + %4f -> " %(i, freq, amp, cutoff, end_time, penalty_inc, stab_inc))
```

and the result is like:

```
Loadcase:   5001  1   50 19.00 20.00 0.000000 + 0.000000 -> 0.495386 (ok)
Loadcase:   5002  2   50 9.50 10.00 0.000000 + 0.000000 -> 0.255045 (ok)
Loadcase:   5003  3   50 6.33 6.67 0.000000 + 0.000000 -> 0.151464 (ok)
Loadcase:   5005  5   50 3.80 4.00 0.000000 + 0.000000 -> 0.116979 (ok)
Loadcase:   5010 10   50 1.90 2.00 0.000000 + 0.000000 -> 0.081181 (ok)
```

I simply want the floats to be right aligned and some spaces inserted where necessary. I really basically want the table to be nicely aligned.
My guess of writing %2.2f seems to be ignored.

I cannot use numpy for technical reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `%2.2f` means. It means "give the float 2 columns total, and display 2 positions after the radix point". Perhaps you want `%5.2f` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is

```
% fieldwidth . precision conversiontype
```

So in you want to leave some space, and show 2 decimals, try

```
%8.2f
```

See [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for a full overview.

Answer (score 3):

The format string  `"%4.2f"` says: format with 2 digits after radix point and use at least 4 characters **for the full string**. So

```
 "%4.2f" % 1.1   -->  " 1.1"
 "%4.2f" % 11.1  -->  "11.1"
 "%4.2f" % 111.1 -->  "111.1"
```

In your case you have the set the `4` above high enough.